# Starting a service as local administrator in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, elastic-stack, filebeat

This might seem a silly question but I'd like to know, if I started a service using the Local Administrator account in the PC and switch to another user, is that service running on that user?

Long story:
I installed filebeat as a service in a PC using its Local Administrator account and started the service there. I'd like to know if that service is still running in another user account using that same PC.

I've checked the task manager and it seems to show that it's running but is it really? I've collected logs for the Administrator account but it doesn't seem to send logs from the user account.

Thanks

Comment: What is displayed in the "Log On" tab in the `services.msc` MMC snap-in?

Comment: Also, please clarify if you mean to manually started the process by directly executing the executable image or if you actually started a Windows service by using `sc start` or `net start` (both commands are equivalent).

Comment: I'll check later on the services.msc. But on my local PC, it's under This Account: Local Service.

I started the service using `Start-Service filebeat` command as per the documentation found in [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-starting.html)

Comment: Services run independently of the logged-on user(s).  That's what they're for!  Switching user has no effect on services.  Nor does installing a service attach it to your account, unless the installer asked for your username and password.

Comment: Are they installed independently as well? When I installed filebeat, I installed it under the local administrator account. Do I need to install it in the user account and start it from there as well? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, of course they are installed independently as well.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment:

> But on my local PC, it's under This Account: Local Service

"Local Service" is a special built-in Windows user account which provides a reduced set of privileges for the service. So to answer your question: the service process **is not** running as your "Administrator" user, nor as an administrator-level user.

Your `Start-Service` command didn't start the service or service process directly, instead it sends a message to the Service Control Manager to then start the service.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684188(v=vs.85).aspx

> The `LocalService` account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. This account is not recognized by the security subsystem, so you cannot specify its name in a call to the `LookupAccountName` function. It has minimum privileges on the local computer and presents anonymous credentials on the network.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

How come when I ran the service using the Local Administrator and switched to another user, the service was showing that it was still running even if I already switched users?

Simply put, If I ran the service using the Local Administrator account and switched users, is that service still running?

Comment: @paaaaat Windows is a multiuser operating system that allows processes from different users to run simultaneously, and Service processes do not run in a desktop-session, they run in a different session (Task Manager can show the Session ID column if you enable it). Additionally, different sessions for local users are used when you use Windows' "Switch User" feature (when two local users are logged-in simultaneously).

Comment: So then, when I started the service under the local administrator account, that service runs only on that session, not on the session of another user? Am I correct?

Comment: @paaaaat, NO.  The service runs *independently of the user sessions*.  (Technically, it runs in "session zero".)